# Does the Piercer feat work with spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, attack

Does the [Piercer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/piercer) feat (TCoE, p. 80) work with spells?

The list of spells it would work with isn't long - *thorn whip* seems to be the only option, really - but does it work?

Comment: Ice knife should also qualify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

The Piercer feat (as well as its siblings Crusher and Slasher) works with any attack roll that deals piercing (or bludgeoning and slashing, respectively) damage against a creature, be it a weapon attack or a spell attack. The feat does not restrict you to only weapons.
From *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (added emphasis by me)

> [...] when you hit a creature *with an attack that deals piercing damage*, you can reroll one of the *attack's damage dice*, and you must use the new roll.